# Why are my map values being reset after i exit a loop

Tags: c++, dictionary, for-loop, object

I have a map named monthly_volumes within an object's member function and every time it finishes making the assignments to the map's value fields, the values are reset to 0(the value i initialized the map with before)

```
for (auto i : monthly_volumes) {
            i.second = get_monthly_volume(i.first, year);
            cout << "Month check during loop" << i.first << ":" << i.second << endl;
        }

        for (auto i : monthly_volumes) {
            //i.second = get_monthly_volume(i.first, year);
            cout << "Month Check After loop" << i.first << ":" << i.second << endl;
        }
```

This is the
[Output of the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gbb7T.png)

Answer (score 1):

You need to iterate through the map with a reference, like this:

```
for (auto &i : monthly_volumes) 
  // changes to i, changes monthly_volumes
```

Also, in c++17 you could use structured bindings to make the code easier to read:

```
for (auto &[k, v] : monthly_volumes) {
    v = get_monthly_volume(k, year);
    cout << "Month check during loop" << k << ":" << v << endl;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know even within the same function i had t explicitly reference them.

Comment: That's correct. c++ has mostly value-semantics, which means everything is a copy, unless you say otherwise. (Consult your textbook for more details).

Answer (score 0):

You need a reference to the map entries to change them. Your code is changing a copy of the map entry.

```
for (auto& i : monthly_volumes) {
        i.second = get_monthly_volume(i.first, year);
        cout << "Month check during loop" << i.first << ":" << i.second << endl;
    }
```